# Import flutter library or dart library just once

Tags: flutter, dart, import

I have main.dart file and home_page.dart file

```
home_page.dart:
______________________________________
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
/* 
Using flutter lib...
*/
```

```
main.dart:
______________________________________
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:mypackage/home_page.dart'; // this library already using flutter material.dart
/* 
Using flutter lib...
*/
```

We can see, main.dart importing flutter library twice, I'm afraid it will waste storage and memory.

How to import `package:flutter/material.dart` once?

Because I want use that library/framework in repeteadly at separate files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importing a library twice will not use twice the memory!

When you add a library to your dependencies or dev dependencies (on the `pubspec.yaml` file) you download the dependency, this includes flutter, any subsequent imports only really make the dependency's API visible to the file.

**Importing doesn't consume memory, depending does**

When you import flutter you are saying. "*Hello flutter, I would like to use some of the classes/variables you have defined on the `material.dart` file*" both of your files ask this of flutter, but there is only *one* flutter.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't worry about consuming memory.

On the other hand, you can create one file imports.dart, and use export

```
export 'package:flutter/material.dart';
export 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

and then import only this file

```
import 'imports.dart';
```

Comment: How about using ```part``` and ```part of``` keyword? Currently I'm using my own solution? In main.dart i'm using ```import 'package:flutter/material.dart;part 'package:mypkg/home_page.dart;```. while home_page.dart ```part of 'package:mypkg/main.dart';```